# difference between "Has won" and "won"

Tags: grammar, tense, present-perfect, past-simple

Should I use "**Has won**" or "**won**" in the following context?

Here's the text:

> John: Subha, did you know our school team **has won/won** today's soccer match? 
>   Me: No! I didn't know that.

With the reference of **today**, should I use "**simple past"** or "**present perfect"** tense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different usage of "simple past tense" and "present perfect"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174533/different-usage-of-simple-past-tense-and-present-perfect)

Answer (score 1):

> — [...] did you know our school team **has won** today's soccer match. (= recent news)
>   —  [...] did you know our school team **won** today's soccer match. (= earlier in the morning, for example)

The choice hinges profoundly upon how *recent* is the action.

Comment: The choice may hinge "profoundly" upon how recent the action is, but that doesn't mean Present Perfect doesn't work in contexts like *Did you know our school team has won several matches against your team? Although I will admit that we haven't beaten you for several years now*. The ***primary*** issue is simply ***relevance** to time of speaking*, which can be for many reasons besides recency.